# Get a c++ pointer to a Python instance using Boost::Python

Tags: c++, python, boost, scripting, boost-python

I am working on embedding Python inside of a C++ application. When I create a new object in Python, I want to be able to store a reference to that Object in my C++ application, so that I can later call methods on that object. What's the recommended way of doing this?

For Example, I would like to be able to do something like this :

**Entity.py**

```
class Entity:
    def getPointer(self)
        return pointertoSelf;
```

**Manager.cpp**

```
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import Entity");
PyRun_SimpleString("entity = Entity.Entity()");

pointerToPythonObj* = somehowGetPointerToObj("entity");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to query into the namespace in which the `entity` object was created, then store a handle to the `entity` object as a [`boost::python::object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/object.html#object-spec).  When interacting with Python objects from C++, it is best to use `boost::python::object` whenever possible, as it provides a high-level notation that acts much like a Python variable.  Additionally, it provides the appropriate reference counting to manage the lifetime of the Python object.  For example, storing a raw pointer (i.e. `pointerToPythonObj*` ) would not extend the life of the Python object; if the Python object was garbage collected from within the interpreter, then `pointerToPythonObj` would be a dangling pointer.

---

Here is an example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47ce432dd68e28be) this:

Entity.py:

```python
class Entity:
    def action(self):
        print "in Entity::action"
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main()
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  try
  {
    Py_Initialize(); // Start interpreter.

    // Create the __main__ module.
    python::object main = python::import("__main__");
    python::object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");

    // Import Entity.py, and instantiate an Entity object in the
    // global namespace.  PyRun_SimpleString could also be used,
    // as it will default to running within and creating 
    // __main__'s namespace.
    exec(
        "import Entity\n"
        "entity = Entity.Entity()\n"
      , main_namespace
    );

    // Obtain a handle to the entity object created from the previous
    // exec.
    python::object entity = main_namespace["entity"];
    // Invoke the action method on the entity.
    entity.attr("action")();
  }
  catch (const python::error_already_set&)
  {
    PyErr_Print();
  }
}
```

Running the above program results in the following output:

```
in Entity::action
```

If `Entity.py` is failing to be imported, then it may require adding its containing directory to the [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable.